# How to log name and parameters of javascript function when a js error occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `window.onerror` & `$(document).ajaxError`  method and I am aware that I can get the js name and line number. But in my case the js files are minified and clubbed because of which both these information are obsolete for me.

Is their any way by which I can log the name **and parameters** of the function  where the error occurred.

Comment: To be fair to Varun - this question is not a duplicate! Varun - there is no way to get meaningful stack trace once you minify your JS files. That is the reason why your build process should ensure your code runs in un-minified format in dev environment. That way if you face any problems you can fire up your dev build, reproduce the problem and debug it using the stack trace in un-minified version. Hope that helps!

Comment: The data which I am logging currently points  me towards a particular function but I am not sure whether it is the one causing error. Is their any way by which  I can log some runtime information about that function for eg ... surround the code(from where that function gets called)  with a try and catch block and log something from error object ... Suggestions will appreciated ..

Comment: In firebug set a break point on the line before the line causing this problem. You can see the stack when the debugger stops on the break point.

Comment: The js error I am talking here is not reproduce-able on local and dev. I want to put some loggers in prod. so that I can get enough information to reproduce it on local.

Comment: There can't be a problem you can't reproduce in dev. Only thing is - you have to find the way to reproduce it. Sometimes problems may be data dependent. Find out what data produces the problem.